# Stop restoring view in eclipse E4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have a requirement that few view part should restore state after restart of eclipse RCP application, but few views should not restore the state . In eclipse 3.x it was quite easy, we just have to configure restorable false for the views which does not require restore. Is there any way to achieve the same behaviour in eclipse 4 as well.

I.e., view will not persist the state after restarting of application(we need to save/ restore state so we can not use -clearPersistedState parameter).

Comment: [This question](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/801627/) is similar but doesn't have a complete resolution

Comment: Ok, this solution is not working for me as I have multiple instances of same part and the solution mentioned in the link only hide one of them not all.
Is there a way to get all open parts of the perspective/application?